# Laravel Debugbar can't import class/class not found

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to set up debugbar as shown here:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

in my Controller, i use

```
Debugbar::info($object);
```

if i try to import i get the response, "class not found" i also use

`cache:clear`
and
`cache:config`
but the result remains the same.

Any idea what i'm missing.

also `dd($request`) in the same controller does nothing a all.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using? how are you "importing/aliasing" this class in your code?

Comment: 8.X ...........

Comment: "laravel/framework": "^8.40",

Comment: add the alias to `config/app.php`, then make sure to `php artisan config:cache` if you had previously cached it

Comment: you mean this:   'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,? it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have `dont-discover` defined in your `composer.json`? What happens if you run `php artisan package:discover`?

Comment: Please share your controller code

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i don't know? It is an empty array:    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },

Answer (score 0):

If you stumple aboute this question, or a similar i use now:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope#introduction

3 Commands C$P

then dump($request)

See whats going on at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/telescope/dumps

Finally sth.  which hopefully works.